# What is the function of `with` parameter when selecting dataframe subset

Tags: r

I encounter this code in one of the Kaggle Notebook:

```
corrplot.mixed(corr = cor(videos[,c("category_id","views","likes",
                                    "dislikes","comment_count"),with=F]))
```

videos is a `data.frame`
"category_id","views","likes","dislikes","comment_count" are columns in the videos `data.frame`

Would like to understand what is the function of the `with` parameter when selecting dataframe subset?

Comment: is is probably a  [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @user20650 it might be a `data.table`. Although in this case your code should work even without `with = F`.

Consider this example :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 5:1, c = 1:5)
```

To subset column `a` and `b` using character vector you could do

```
dt[, c('a', 'b'), with = F]

#   a b
#1: 1 5
#2: 2 4
#3: 3 3
#4: 4 2
#5: 5 1
```

However, as mentioned this would work the same without `with = F`.

```
dt[, c('a', 'b')]
```

`with = F` is helpful when you have a vector of column names stored in a variable.

```
cols <- c('a', 'b')
dt[, cols] ##Error
dt[, cols, with = F] ##Works
```